# Reflecting a DLL that is also a part of the project type collision

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm currently running into a type clash.  I have two projects, A and B.  A has B as a dependency.  When A runs, it runs an OpenFileDialog and loads the given assembly with

```
var assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(selectedPath);
```

Then, later in my code, I'm having my types clash.  I have a reflected function I chose to invoke as so

```
var result = WindowData.SelectedFunction.Invoke(null, parameters);
```

It's a static function, so I don't pass in an object for the first parameter.  Obviously the second set is an object[] of the parameters.

So it seems the referenced assembly and the one I'm (not actually?) loading are colliding.  It's weird because this DOES NOT happen in debug mode in a watch.